# Create Javascript Alert on button click using Code behind in C#

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, button

I am using the below code to create a button in code behind and also create confirm message box for that button.But its not working please help me to create this..

```
Button btn2 = new Button();
btn2.Attributes.Add(
    "OnClientClick", 
    "if (confirm(''Are you sure you want to add this estimate data?')) return;");

if(true) 
{
    //Do something
}
```

Comment: How does the button know where it belongs to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use below code:-

```
btn2.Attributes["onClick"] = "return confirm('Are you sure you want to add this   estimate data??');"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
btn2.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:return confirm('Are you sure you want to add this    estimate data??')");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code:

```
btn2.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return confirm('Are you sure you want to add this estimate data?');")
```

Answer (score 1):

you can add ajaxcotoroll toolkit reference to your website and dynamically create confirm for every button

```
Button btn2 = new Button();
btn.ID="buttonID";
ConfirmButtonExtender confirm = new ConfirmButtonExtender();
confirm.TargetControlID = "buttonID";
confirm.ConfirmText="Are you sure you want to add this    estimate data??'";
```

Comment: urgh AjaxControlToolkit! nasty

Comment: It is the lazy way for a .net developer to do Client side UI.

Comment: @Tim B James   whaaaatttt???? there is a reason why ajaxtoolkit is supported to be created from server side, it a lot better than writing a JavaScript on server side, it a lot simpler and cleaner to control, and what you consider a good way ????

Comment: I wouldn't do any server side `onclick` stuff. I would assign the button a `data-` attribute to hold the text, give it a class `confirm-btn`, and then keep all the confirm/onclick on the client side. Need another confirm button? just give it a `data-` attribute and class. Need to add a button client side? just give is a `data-` attribute and class. Never need to recompile anything if you want to change the client ui.

Comment: what if it dynamic and every message is dynamic in the alert and you do not know how many button are going to be generated if you give them all the same class they will most likely implement the same confirm message and if  you are using and old framework like 2.0 I am not sure if it even supports attributes and if it going to render  in HTML5

Comment: You are still dynamically adding the `data-` attribute with the confirm messeage. Do you know anything about how javascript/jQuery work? Doesn't matter if they all have the same class. Also, `data-` attributes have absolutely nothing to do with the .net framework. There are client side plugins to provide support for it's usage.

Comment: 1 why would I want to use client side plugin to do something as simple as this, and yes it does because you are adding the attribute from the sever side and in order to do this you need to use . Attribute which again I am not sure if available in all frameworks and why would I ever want to do that when i do not modify absolutely anything without going back to the server side since based on your approach all i do is read the data attribute that contains message and then dispalys it back using same function

Comment: stilt do not get what you want to prove or your point maybe you never used ajaxcontroltoolkit you never expalined why in your case client side is better than ajaxcontolltoolkit

Answer (score 0):

Try this Cod:

```
 Button yourbtnid = new Button();
 yourbtnid.ID="Button1";
 ConfirmButtonExtender conf = new ConfirmButtonExtender();
 conf.TargetControlID = "Button1";
 conf.ConfirmText="Are you sure you want to add this    estimate data??'";
```

This is using Ajaxcontroll call..

OR

```
Button yourbtnid = new Button();
yourbtnid.Attributes.Add(
     "OnClientClick", 
     "return confirm('Are you sure you want to add this    estimate data??');");
```